# CSS make child to topmost using z-index

Tags: css, z-index

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZVVbY

I want the code above of the green box to be topmost.

But apparently, it's under another small z-index container.

I don't want to change parent z-index. How to achieve this?

> Not to change the z-index of parent and other parent

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container1 {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.container3 {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2200000;
}
.container4 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.container5 {
  background: gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2"></div>
  <div class="container3"></div>
</div>

<div class="container4">
  <div class="container5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to change the z-index. I do not think there is another way

Comment: Is there a way not to change the container's z-index?

Comment: The yellow container must cover on top of the red container. And the green component needs to be top of the gray, yellow and red.

Comment: `container1` (the red div) and `container4` (the red yellow)  are the main parents of the other divs, You want the green div which is inside the red div to be on top while the red one is below the yellow, this impossible the way your html is structured, either change the z-index or your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that having a z-index on `container1` is creating a layer stack. This results in all child elements with a z-index to be relative to the parents z-index. In order to make this work removing the z-index style from `container` will get the effect you're wanting.

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container1 {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.container2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.container3 {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
.container4 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.container5 {
  background: gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
 
<div with z-index=1 class="container1" >
    <div class="container2"></div>
    <div with z-index=100 class="container3" ></div>
</div>

<div with z-index=2 class="container4" >
  <div class="container5"></div>
</div>
```